# Web3OnboardProvider is undefined after importing, won't wrap Component without throwing error

Tags: web3js

Not sure what could be happening here. I'm using the boilerplate code from this repository:
https://github.com/blocknative/web3-onboard/tree/v2-web3-onboard-develop/examples/with-nextjs

Here's the code for _app.js

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import { Web3OnboardProvider, init } from '@web3-onboard/react'
import injectedModule from '@web3-onboard/injected-wallets'

const INFURA_KEY = ''

const ethereumRopsten = {
  id: '0x3',
  token: 'rETH',
  label: 'Ethereum Ropsten',
  rpcUrl: `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_KEY}`
}

const polygonMainnet = {
  id: '0x89',
  token: 'MATIC',
  label: 'Polygon',
  rpcUrl: 'https://matic-mainnet.chainstacklabs.com'
}

const chains = [ethereumRopsten, polygonMainnet]
const wallets = [injectedModule()]

const web3Onboard = init({
  wallets,
  chains,
  appMetadata: {
    name: "Web3-Onboard Demo",
    icon: '<svg>My App Icon</svg>',
    description: "A demo of Web3-Onboard."
  }
})

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Web3OnboardProvider web3Onboard={web3Onboard}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Web3OnboardProvider>
  )
}
```

This is the error I'm being shown
[image: Error after running locally]

Any insight would be great

export default MyApp

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a string to the `const INFURA_KEY`

That string being your Infura API key

It's generally more secure to add the key to an .env file and make your `const` a call to node `process.env` `$INFURA_KEY`

Comment: Code provided is not exact for ie. the first sentence has a traditional english language context melded with code. Considering the complexity of the code structure or lack thereof, I believe most will understand well enough to derive their own accurate resolution